# setting the pace of a character

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I want to define a function to set the speed to characters in my game, I understand there is a formula for this:

```
rate * time = distance

 1. Establish a rate of movement in whatever units of measure you want (such as pixels per millisecond).
 2. Get the time since the last update that has passed (elapsed time).
 3. Establish the direction of movement .
```

I have tryied to define a method which implements this:

```
def speed(self, speed):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()       
    milliseconds = clock.tick(60)  # milliseconds passed since last frame
    seconds = milliseconds / 1000.0
    speed = seconds * (self.dx+self.dy)
```

But when I call this method to change the speed of my character, nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you do anything with speed? Where do you call this function?

Comment: It seems you forgot to add `return speed`.

Comment: Is this to *set* speed or to *get* it? Why does it have an argument `speed`?

Comment: this is meant to be set speed

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `self` keyword so set a class attribute in a method. But in your method you use speed as a parameter which I don't believe is how you want to use it.

```
def speed(self, speed):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()       
    milliseconds = clock.tick(60)  # milliseconds passed since last frame
    seconds = milliseconds / 1000.0
    speed = seconds * (self.dx+self.dy)
```

This method takes a speed and then sets it equal to something and then it goes out of of scope with out making a change. To set an objects `speed` attribute with a method you would:

```
def set_speed(self):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()       
    milliseconds = clock.tick(60)  # milliseconds passed since last frame
    seconds = milliseconds / 1000.0
    self.speed = seconds * (self.dx+self.dy)
```

`self` is the way to reference an object from inside one of it's methods. `self.speed = 10` equates to doing `my_object.speed = 10` outside the method. Using this method:

```
class Character:
    def __init__():
        self.speed = 0  # your character class needs to have a speed attribute somewhere

hero = Character()  # creates an object that represents your character
hero.set_speed()  # call the method to set the speed attribute of the character class
```

Comment: this doesnt change the speed of the character

Comment: why would you call hero.set_speed() if you cant pass a speed inside it?

Comment: In your example you passed a `speed` parameter to the method but all you did with it was set it equal to something else. You didn't use it's value I assumed you wanted to calculate a new speed and then set the classes `speed` attribute to that value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you have everything set up, but here is a rough example using 2-tuples `(x, y)` for `position` and `speed` (I think you might have `self.x, self.y` for my `self.position` and `self.dx, self.dy` for my `self.speed`, but the principles are the same):

```
def Character(object):

    def __init__(self, position):
        self.position = position # e.g. (200, 100)
        self.speed = (0, 0) # start stationary

    def move(self, elapsed):
        """Update Character position based on speed and elapsed time."""
        #                            distance =  time    * rate
        # position    =       old position    +  distance
        self.position = (int(self.position[0] + (elapsed * self.speed[0])),
                         int(self.position[1] + (elapsed * self.speed[1])))
```

Note that you don't need to work out how far a `Character` should travel for a given speed when you *set* `self.speed`, just when you try to `move` the `Character`. You can directly access `character.speed`; having a "setter" method (e.g. `set_speed(self, speed)`) is unpythonic.

Now you could call this:

```
hero = Character(start_loc)
framerate = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
...
while True: # main gameplay loop
    elapsed = clock.tick(60) # update world time and get elapsed
    ...
    hero.speed = (2, 0) # travelling horizontally in the positive x-direction
    hero.move(elapsed) # update the hero's position
```

Note that speed here would be in units of pixels per millisecond.